Godot (4.3) Windows Export issue, unexpected C# script behaviour
On Godot engine, I created a generator that throw on the map various references of objets, and compare if positions are available, It is entirely based on C# code and uses the classic windows export.It makes a lot of calculation, so you expect some latency before the calculation is done.
The exported version don't read properly the code, so the generator is non functional.
Here is the exported result when the map is drawn :
4 memorized asset 4 4 14 14 4 4 || spots 14 0 0 14 || assets on map 0 0 0 0
ERROR: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'index')
at Godot.Collections.Array.GetVariantBorrowElementAt(Int32 index, godot_variant& elem)
at Godot.Collections.Array`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
at Godot.Node.InvokeGodotClassMethod(godot_string_name& method, NativeVariantPtrArgs args, godot_variant& ret)
at WorldBehaviour2.InvokeGodotClassMethod(godot_string_name& method, NativeVariantPtrArgs args, godot_variant& ret) 4
at Godot.Bridge.CSharpInstanceBridge.Call(IntPtr godotObjectGCHandle, godot_string_name* method, godot_variant** arg)
at: void Godot.NativeInterop.ExceptionUtils.LogException(System.Exception) (:0)
And here is the expected result on the simulation :
4 memorized asset 4 4 4 4 4 4 || spots 0 0 0 0 || assets on map 0 0 0 0
spots on map 31 dia [49, 74, 70, 51, 72, 66, 47, 73, 51, 81, 67, 52, 83, 46, 81, 46, 60, 69, 56, 69, 43, 63, 51, 57, 45, 52, 63, 58, 48, 45, 46]
Memorized items seems to be placed on different list slot for no reason, and the code don't use specific library that migth not be exported properly
The code is way too long, so I give you a short description of the logic :
public override void _Ready() {
    SetDefault();
    CallDeferred(nameof(DrawLargeMap));
}

// Once the code starts
public void DrawLargeMap() {
    DrawCoverage(100); // Generate 100 Vector3 and add them on a Vector3 list
        
    // For each spot we select items
    for (int i = 0 ; i < spots.Count ; i++) {
        SelectObj(context[i]);  // select objets on a list
                // For each selected object, we define the object properties on list
                for (int j = 0 ; j < selectedObj.Count ; j++) {
            SelectOnMap(i, selectedObj[j]); // select objets No already drawn on a list
                        (...)
                        SetOnMap(); // Set the objet on some list that define it's properties
                }
        }
}

Each called method are basic void method with parameters, no async or whatever, every list are likes this :
[Export]
public Godot.Collections.Array<Vector3> spots { get; set; }
[Export]
public Godot.Collections.Array<int> spotDiameter { get; set; }
public Godot.Collections.Array<Vector3> spotMap { get; set; }
[Export]
public Godot.Collections.Array<Vector3> context { get; set; }

I tried to tackle this unexpected behaviour by reducing the cost of the map generation, removing the "call deferred" by a more simple call method, and even adding it on the update, it seems to be the same issue, the code simply don't behave the same way.
I can't run each method separately on specific call deferred without breaking the logic (Need to be read in a specific order), and I don't really need to run it in realtime.
My only known issue could be the used list system, or low level memory reading that migth not be used the way I intended by the dotnet environment, I don't know the answer
It seems that threads could be used, but I don't really know how to use it or if it's useful here ..
Is there any known export issue on C# with the windows export for 4.3 Godot, or any security/reading memory tweak when it's packed as a product ?

With further researches and trials, I find out that it is definitely a memory access issue,
The CallDeferred() function have the same memory limitation, so calling my big method like this doesn't match,
I can't use mutexes or thread, because it breaks your code when manipulating list or asset on the main scene, this is annoying ..
Is there any way to add a node with it script to a specific running safe space and then adding it to the main scene ?
Her is the doc link :
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.3/tutorials/threads/thread_safe_apis.html

Well https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.3/tutorials/threads/thread_safe_apis.html#threads
It seems that using dynamic list is the most critical problem, so using list that use .Add() or .RemoveAt or anything that change the size of the list is a problem, Unity user are warned. In some cases, adding only a single item migth be OK, but not simultanéus changes. Memory issue is still hard to predict, It always break somewhere randomly, I don't find any proper solution to predict this instability
